# What is the Chrome Dev Tools "Hit Test" timeline entry?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When looking at a Chrome Dev Tools timeline I noticed that there was a "Hit Test" entry every time somethings happens:

[image]

Does anyone know what it is? I've done my googling, but am still at a loss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A hit test is how a contact (mouse/touch) event is checked to see what it "hit" in the DOM.

https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/compositor-hit-testing describes some of this.

Comment: Ah, of course. I should have tried searching a bit longer :) Thanks!

Comment: Why is it coming up BEFORE the touchStart in our trace @Kariudo though?